# rowDiffs type function, keeping "row 1" as the reference row per group

Tags: r

Say I have this simple data frame with a grouping variable, and three xs per group:

```
df<-data.frame(grp=rep(letters[1:3],each=3),
               x=rnorm(9))

  grp          x
1   a  1.9561455
2   a -2.3916438
3   a  0.7267603
4   b -0.8794693
5   b -0.3089820
6   b -1.7228825
7   c -0.3964017
8   c -0.6237301
9   c -0.1522535
```

I want to, per group, take the initial row as a reference row, and get the difference between x and this reference x (first row) for all rows, such that the outcome is:

```
  grp          x      xdiff
1   a  1.9561455  0.0000000
2   a -2.3916438 -4.3477893
3   a  0.7267603 -1.2293853
4   b -0.8794693  0.0000000
5   b -0.3089820  0.5704873
6   b -1.7228825 -0.8434132
7   c -0.3964017  0.0000000
8   c -0.6237301 -0.2273284
9   c -0.1522535  0.2441482
```

I was able to do it through this way:

```
rowOne<-df %>% group_by(grp) %>% filter(row_number()==1)
names(rowOne)[2]<-"x_initial"
df %>% left_join(rowOne) %>% mutate(xdiff=x-x_initial)
```

But I'm hoping there is a simpler way to do it, that doesn't require creating new datasets, merging and subtracting.

I have a dozen or so columns I need to do this for, and I'd like to be able to just do something like:

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(xdiff=rowDiffs(x))
```

But, obviously, this is not the correct function. Is there a function out there I haven't come across, or an easier way to program R to do this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a column by the first value in the column grouped by another column can be done using either `data.table` or `dplyr` or `base R` methods.

If we are doing this for a single column, the compact data.table method is one option.  We convert 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by the grouping column ('grp'), we get the difference between the column ('x') and the first value in that column (`x[1L]` - Note that I used the integer representation i.e. 1L.  It would also work by simply using `x[1]`.  In some cases, the integers might be a bit faster).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, xdiff:=x-x[1L] , by = grp]
```

Or a similar option with `dplyr` is piping (`%>%`) the arguments from left to right, ie. use the dataset ('df'), then we group by 'grp', and create a new column using `mutate`.  Note that there is a `first` function in `dplyr` to select the first observation.  It has also other arguments (`?first`).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(xdiff= x- first(x))
```

Or a `base R` option suggested by @David Arenburg

```
df$xdiff <- with(df, ave(x, grp), FUN = function(x) x - x[1L])
```

---

If you have many columns, we can use `mutate_each` (from `dplyr`) after the grouping step, change the column names with `setNames` (NOTE: If there is mutliple functions i.e. >1, we could change it within the `mutate_each` itself), and bind the original columns with `bind_cols`.

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(.-first(.))) %>%
  setNames(., c(names(df1)[1L], paste0(names(df1)[-1L], 'diff'))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  bind_cols(df1, .)
```

Or using `data.table`, we can create new columns by assigning (`:=`).  Here, we loop the columns under consideration with `lapply` (.SD is the `Subset of DataTable`) and get the difference grouped by 'grp'.

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), 'grp')
setDT(df1)[, paste0(nm1, 'diff') :=lapply(.SD, function(x) x-x[1L]), grp]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- cbind(df, y= rnorm(9))
```

Comment: And `with(df, ave(x, grp), FUN = function(x) x - x[1L])` ofcourse

Comment: @AndrewTaylor In `first` there is an option `order_by`.  I never used it before.